# JSF: Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource exception

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2

I have existing application written with some kind of hand-made JSP. It contains one class derived from `HttpServlet` handling all requests and its own HTML template language. I am trying to rewrite it using common JSF templating syntax. Right now I am trying to rewrite one set of pages. So I did the following:
I registered new servlet entry in web.xml  (class - `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet`, url pattern - `/jsp/*` ) 
and put this code in old servlet class:

```
ExistingServlet::doGet(request, response)
{
    // some old code
    if(page we are going to is my new page)
    {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/myNewPage.xhtml");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        return;
    }
}
```

But if I am going to this page I got the following exception:

> /myNewPage.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

With this call stack (last lines):

```
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:265)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:201)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:227)
```

Please tell me what is wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

When you map the FacesServlet to the URL pattern `/jsp/*`, and access the page `/jsp/myNewPage.xhtml`, the associated ResourceResolver will attempt to lookup the resource with path `/myNewPage.xhtml` using the `ExternalContext`, and in turn the `ServletContext`object.

This would imply that the `myNewPage.xhtml` page must be present in the `WebContent`, failing which an error would be reported. By inference, you must place the `myNewPage.xhtml` page under WebContent or refer to the page using the `/jsp/<sub-directory-path>/myNewPage.xhtml` URL in your servlet, where the sub-directory-path refers to the directory path under the WebContent directory.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean with "WebContent". I am using netbeans 7. In project settings I have "Web pages folder" option set to "web pages dir". My new page lies in "web pages dir/jsp/myNewPage.xhtml". Where I should move it exactly from there?

Comment: 'WebContent' refer to the root directory of your web project and WAR file, that contains the WEB-INF directory and other web resources. I believe that given the way you've configured Netbeans, it would be the "web pages dir". So, your myNewPage.xhtml file should be moved to the "web pages dir" directory.

Comment: Inside .war file directories sorted like this:  
/WEB-INF/  
/jsp/myNewPage.xhtml  
/resources/css/...  
/some-old-html-dirs/

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if your comment is formatted correctly, but JSF does not allow for placing JSPs or facelets in the WEB-INF directory. If you are placing your facelets in the publicly accessible content of the WAR, then `myNewPage.xhtml` should be in the root of the WAR, and not in the `/jsp` sub-directory.

Comment: I dont know how to put linebreaks here. I mean what WEb-INF and my /jsp/ dir are at the same level, not one included in another.

Comment: See my last comment. I believe it should clarify where you JSP file should be located.

Comment: I created this /jsp dir to separate my new code from old one. Is it possible to get iw working using subfolders inside "Web pages folder"? I dont care how it will look inside .war file.

Comment: Yes, that's quite possible. Use `/jsp/jsp/myNewPage.xhtml` in the servlet, as stated in the answer.

Comment: I tried to put my pages (actual page and template to the root of .war file, tried to set /jsp/jsp/ in forward(), set /jsp/jsp/ in servlet pattern but I either getting old error or I have my page transfered by without any conversion, as-is, so IE cannot open it as web page and asking to save it.

Comment: If you intended to use the /jsp directory in your WAR file to store the facelets, then why did you move the pages to the root of the WAR, and also change the path used by the servlet to /jsp/jsp/... ?

Comment: hi Vineet, I have my wecome page (hello.xhtml) in WebContent directory.. and entry in Web.xml is   <welcome-file>hello.xhtml</welcome-file>    but I am getting /hello.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource. I dont understand what is wrong.. Can you help?

Comment: servelt-mappint entry is ::
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>